# What is this technique called

Tags: javascript

I believe this is some semblance of a JavaScript Object Literal but I can find no example if this technique I've found in a project I'm working on. What's it called?

```
const calc = n =>
  ({
    true: 7,
    [n < 50]: 6,
    ...
    [n < 8]: 1,
  }.true); <!-- this '.true' right here?
```

Comment: Not much different to `{true:5, false:1, true:7}.true`. Simply object literal dot property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a dot-notation [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Comment: The OP is very explicitly asking about the `.true` part (as per the comment at the end of their code example).